# Problem with jstree can expand nodes with no children

Tags: jquery, jstree, children, nodes, expand

I'm working with jstree with ajax and I see that all my nodes have the arrow to expand it, even those which have no children. On the demo page of jstree http://www.jstree.com/demo this is not the case. I don't see on the demo code something different from mine, so does it come from the server ? Have I a parameter to put in response of "getChildren" method to say at jstree "this one, have no children, don't enable to expand it"?

Anyone know from where it come from? And what can I do to fix that ?

Because it seems to be a problem when I used the copy / paste function of the contextmenu plugin. When I paste on a node (the new parent) with no children and not yet open (so children haven't been loaded), nothing happen except the request to get children (like if I click to open the node) that return nothing obviously. And it doesn't execute the move_node function.

EDIT : I have the same problem with "add" from the contextmenu

Someone can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a sample on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 9):

From the jsTree documentation:

```
http://www.jstree.com/documentation/html_data
```

one of the three classes will be applied depending on node structure :

```
<li class="[ jstree-open | jstree-closed | jstree-leaf ]">
```

Jonathan Stowell is right, but setting attr.class to "jstree-leaf" won't work (at least not on the latest version).

But "open" and "closed" reminded me of node.state, so I tried, and it turned out that when you set node.**state** to "leaf" in your JSON serialzation class, it will be non-expandable.

Answer (score 4):

I added the `jstree-leaf` class to the `attr` property for my nodes that do not have children.

```
attr: { "class" : "jstree-leaf" }
```

This then sets the CSS class you need to not have the expand feature.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with "create" method and nodes without children. Solved it specifying such nodes' state as "open" instead of the default "closed".

Hopes this helps.

Comment: I had to set this to 'leaf' as per Quandary. 'Closed' didn't work.

Comment: I had to set it to 'Leaf', as well.

Answer (score 1):

if you send json data, give "jstree-leaf" as li_attr's class

```
 li_attr: {class = "jstree-leaf" }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you return the JSON object, if the node does not have children, set the `children` property to `false` and set the `state` property to `false`.